# Evento "touchstart" para un doubletap bloquea el scroll con swipe arriba o abajo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Al agregarle una función al evento "touchstart", buscando que se dispare al "doubletap", evito sin desearlo que el scroll se active al swipe top o down.

```
//DoubleClick obviamente no funciona con doubleTap, so...
$("tbody").on("touchstart", tapHandler);
var tapedTwice = false;
function tapHandler(e) {
    
    if(!tapedTwice) {
        tapedTwice = true;
        setTimeout( function() { tapedTwice = false; }, 300 ); //Si lo quiero apurar o no
        return false;
    }
    e.preventDefault();//Para evitar el zoom
    lightboxPrint(e);  //La función que ocurre al doubletap
 }
```

Bueno, obviamente no quiero que esto pase XD Ya probé para ver que el problema no venga por CSS eliminando todo y llegué al punto en que es esta, y solamente esta, la función que me trae problemas. Si no hay forma de evitar el error, cómo puedo agregarle un scroll al swipe en la tabla? (funciona en el resto del documento, solo funciona mal en el cuerpo de la tabla, donde llamo al evento)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al ponerle "false" a tapedTwice, y retornar un false, no dejo que nunca ocurra el scrolling porque directamente cancelo el "tap", así que la solución es tan simple como hacerlo "al revés".

```
$("tbody").on("touchstart", tapHandler);
var tapedTwice = true;
function tapHandler(e) {
    
    if(tapedTwice) {
        tapedTwice = false;
        setTimeout( function() { tapedTwice = true; }, 300 ); //Si lo quiero apurar o no
        return true;
    }
    e.preventDefault();//Para evitar el zoom
    lightboxPrint(e);  
};
```

Esto hace que el código siga funcionando igual, pero no evita el scroll.